# OAuth access to EWS on behalf of a user

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I have had success using OAuth 2.0 with EWS when using admin permission. Now I am trying to set it up so that an individual user can log in and grant access for himself. So I start a browser with this URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=f3f92d23-29dd-4465-828e-35300884ef61&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient&response_type=code&scope=offline_access%20Calendars.ReadWrite.All%20Contacts.ReadWrite.All%20Mail.ReadWrite.All%20Tasks.ReadWrite%20User.ReadBasic.All
```

The browser allows me to log in to my test account, but then this error is returned:

error=invalid client
description=AADSTS650053 The application 'my app name' asked for scope 'Calendars.ReadWrite.All' that
doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'

In Azure, when looking at the API permissions for my application, I have 11 Exchange permissions, including both Application and Delegated permissions for Calendars.ReadWrite.All, in addition to all of the others that I requested.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because EWS is a legacy API it doesn't implement the more restrictive permission model that the Graph and Outlook REST API uses. The only permission that will work for Delegate access is EWS.AccessAsUser.All (Scope https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All). This gives full access to every folder in a Mailbox (and any mailboxes the user has been granted access to).It looks like you application registration already includes that permission so

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=f3f92d23-29dd-4465-828e-35300884ef61&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient&response_type=code&scope=offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2FEWS.AccessAsUser.All
```

should work

Comment: That does seem to fix it, thanks, you are very helpful as usual.

Comment: It gives `invalid_scope` for Microsoft personal consumer accounts (@outlook.com). Works for Organizational (work or school) accounts